# How to cast aggregated values over a range in R and fill missing range values with zero

Tags: r, casting, range, reshape

How to cast aggregated values over a range in R and fill missing range values with zero.

```r
df <- data.frame (year = sample(c(2014:2016), 100, replace=T),
                  month = sample(c(1:5,8:12), 100, replace=T),
                  int = 1)

# install.packages("reshape")
library(reshape)
month <- cast(df, year ~ month, sum, value = 'int')
month
```

Output:

```
# output
  year 1 2 3 4 5 8 9 10 11 12
1 2014 6 5 4 3 4 4 3  3  9  2
2 2015 4 9 1 3 1 4 3  3  2  3
3 2016 0 3 3 4 4 1 4  1  3  1
```

How do I set the missing months to zero? The result should be like that:

```
# output
  year 1 2 3 4 5 >6< >7< 8 9 10 11 12
1 2014 6 5 4 3 4  0   0  4 3  3  9  2
2 2015 4 9 1 3 1  0   0  4 3  3  2  3
3 2016 0 3 3 4 4  0   0  1 4  1  3  1
```

Is there a way to do it over the cast function?

Comment: excellent question, exactly what I need :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `tidyverse` to convert the 'month' to `factor` with `levels` specified as 1:12, get the `sum` of 'int' grouped by 'year', 'month' and `spread` to 'wide' format with `drop=FALSE`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
   group_by(year, month = factor(month, levels = 1:12)) %>% 
   summarise(int = sum(int)) %>% 
   spread(month, int, drop = FALSE, fill = 0) 
#     year   `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`   `6`   `7`   `8`   `9`  `10`  `11`  `12`
#* <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1  2014     3     2     2     1     2     0     0     4     1     5     5     6
#2  2015     2     7     5     2     4     0     0     5     3     3     4     5
#3  2016     0     4     5     5     2     0     0     3     2     1     5     2
```

---

Or using `dcast` in a single line

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df), year ~ factor(month, levels = 1:12), sum, drop = FALSE)
#   year 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
#1: 2014 3 2 2 1 2 0 0 4 1  5  5  6
#2: 2015 2 7 5 2 4 0 0 5 3  3  4  5
#3: 2016 0 4 5 5 2 0 0 3 2  1  5  2
```

---

Or with `xtabs` from `base R`

```
xtabs(int~year+factor(month, levels = 1:12), df)
```

Comment: Nice answer! I prefer **`xtabs`** as it doesn't require any addition package!

Comment: For **`xtabs`** its helpful to use **`as.data.frame.matrix()`** on the output.

Comment: +1. For the `dcast` solution, you don't need `setDT` and `data.table` at all, just `dcast(df, ...)`. You need to be careful though with `drop = FALSE`, it will expand all unused levels of all factors in the formula, not just the month, so if you don't want that, drop those unwanted levels or don't let the respective factor be a factor (e.g. by using `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when you load the data).

Comment: @TMS  Yes, it will be using `dcast` from `reshape2` as I already loaded both packages.